# What's the difference between B-Tree and GiST index methods (in PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, b-tree, gist-index

I have been working on optimizing my Postgres databases recently, and traditionally, I've only ever use B-Tree indexes.  However, I saw that GiST indexes suport non-unique, multicolumn indexes, in the Postgres 8.3 documentation.

I couldn't, however, see what the actual difference between them is.  I was hoping that my fellow coders might beable to explain, what the pros and cons between them are, and more importantly, the reasons why I would use one over the other?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In a nutshell: B-Tree indexes perform better, but GiST indexes are more flexible. Usually, you want B-Tree indexes if they'll work for your data type. There was a recent post on the PG lists about a huge performance hit for using GiST indexes; they're expected to be slower than B-Trees (such is the price of flexibility), but not *that* much slower... work is, as you might expect, ongoing.

From [a post by Tom Lane](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/2009-04/msg00272.php), a core PostgreSQL developer:

> The main point of GIST is to be able to index queries that simply are
>   not indexable in btree.  ...  One would fully
>   expect btree to beat out GIST for btree-indexable cases.  I think the
>   significant point here is that it's winning by a factor of a couple
>   hundred; that's pretty awful, and might point to some implementation
>   problem.

Answer (score 6):

Basically everybody's right - btree is default index as it performs very well. GiST are somewhat different beasts - it's more of a "framework to write index types" than a index type on its own. You have to add custom code (in server) to use it, but on the other hand - they are very flexible.

Generally - you don't use GiST unless the datatype you're using tell you to do so. Example of datatypes that use GiST: ltree (from contrib), tsvector (contrib/tsearch till 8.2, in core since 8.3), and others.

There is well known, and pretty fast geographic extenstion to PostgreSQL - PostGIS (http://postgis.refractions.net/) which uses GiST for its purposes.

Answer (score 2):

GiST indexes are lossy to an extent, meaning that the DBMS has to deal with false positives/negatives, i.e.:

> GiST indexes are lossy because each document is represented in the index by a fixed-
>   length signature. The signature is
>   generated by hashing each word into a
>   random bit in an n-bit string, with
>   all these bits OR-ed together to
>   produce an n-bit document signature.
>   When two words hash to the same bit
>   position there will be a false match.
>   If all words in the query have matches
>   (real or false) then the table row
>   must be retrieved to see if the match
>   is correct.
>   b-trees do not have this behavior, so depending on the data being indexed, there may be some performance difference between the two.

See for text search behavior http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-indexes.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/indexes-types.html for a general purpose comparison.

Comment: Where is this quote from? I don't believe GIST is inherently lossy, so I'm guessing this is for a specific type, perhaps for text.

Comment: It's from the 8.3 doc section in the 1st link (below the 2nd query plan). This is also reflected in the corresponding section for 9.5.

Comment: Thought so. That's specific to the text search implementation. GiST allows index implementations to be lossy, but they don't have to be.

Answer (score 2):

GiST are more general indexes. You can use them for broader purposes that the ones you would use with B-Tree. Including the ability to build a B-Tree using GiST.

I.E.: you can use GiST to index on geographical points, or geographical areas, something you won't be able to do with B-Tree indexes, since the only thing that matter on a B-Tree is the key (or keys) you are indexing on.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how GiST works better for geographical points, or geographical areas - as this very much falls into what I am using the index for.