# Why in LTree example in Postgresql documentation, the author has created two indexes over the ltree column?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, ltree

Can someone please explain why two indexes mechanism (a btree and a gist) are defined in an example given by [Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ltree.html) (Please Check *F.21.4. Example* section).

This is the example code :

```
CREATE TABLE test (path ltree);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Science');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Science.Astronomy');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Science.Astronomy.Astrophysics');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Science.Astronomy.Cosmology');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Hobbies');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Hobbies.Amateurs_Astronomy');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Stars');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Galaxies');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Astronauts');

CREATE INDEX path_gist_idx ON test USING gist(path);
CREATE INDEX path_idx ON test USING btree(path);
```

At the last two lines, the author has created two indexes on *path* column. why? isn't that Gist enough for the purpose?

In section F.21.3 the author implies that b-tree and gist may speed up the following operators :

> B-tree index over ltree: <, <=, =, >=, >

> GiST index over ltree: <, <=, =, >=, >, @>, <@, @, ~, ?

Which means Gist is enough for all the above operators.let clear my question. Is the author trying to provide example for both indexes here or there is a reason for using both indexes.

I am creating a table with a ltree column and I want to know that should I create both indexes (btree and gist) on my column or gist is just enough?

Comment: I agree, the B-tree index seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

B-tree indices are faster; check this discussion: [What's the difference between B-Tree and GiST index methods (in PostgreSQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766488/whats-the-difference-between-b-tree-and-gist-index-methods-in-postgresql)

So the logic behind creating both indices is that GiST is more flexible and can be used when the method of searching isn't supported by B-tree (the extra `@>, <@, @, ~, ?` that GiST has). However, when you do use the methods common between both (`<, <=, =, >=, >`), B-tree will be used as it is faster.